# Finding the different items in a list compared to its first item of the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `GroupSummary` `class` that has some properties like this in it:

```
public class GroupsSummary
{
    public bool UsedRow { get; set; }

    public string GroupTin   { get; set; }
    public string PayToZip_4 { get; set; }
    public string PayToName  { get; set; }

    public string PayToStr1     { get; set; }
    public string PayToStr2     { get; set; }
    public string PayToCity     { get; set; }
    public string PayToState    { get; set; }
    public bool   UrgentCare_YN { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a `Dictionary` like `<string, List<GroupSummary>`

For each of these dictionary items I first get the values for the `FIRST` item in its list, the ones I am interested in are:

```
PayToStr1,PayToStr2,PayToCity,PayToState
```

Now for the rest of the items in list of that key, ( so from second item) I want to find all the ones that the combination(just string concatenation is fine) 
of their `PayToStr1,PayToStr2,PayToCity,PayToState` is DIFFERENT from the first item I picked above.

What is a good way of writing this? I can do a `for-each loop` and solve it but I was hoping there is some better `LINQ` way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<GroupsSummary> items = new List<GroupsSummary>();

var first = items.First();
var others = from i in items.Skip(1)
             where i.PayToStr1 != first.PayToStr1 ||
                   i.PayToStr2 != first.PayToStr2 ||
                   ....
             select i;
```

or you can define a method inside GroupsSummary like and use it in the where clause:

```
public bool IsDifferentFrom(GroupsSummary other)
{
    return PayToStr1 != other.PayToStr1 ||
           PayToStr2 != other.PayToStr2 ||
           ....;
}

var others = from i in items.Skip(1)
             where i.IsDifferentFrom(first)
             select i;
```

Comment: Definitely the second suggestion -- if your condition ever changes, you want to change the code in *one place*. (Even in the case you can't edit `GroupsSummary`, the same thing can be done with an extension method.)

Comment: like ".Where(first.IsDifferentAddressFrom(i))" ? It doesn't recognize i

Comment: Oh I think it should be: "                var others = from i in items.Skip(1).Where(t => t.IsDifferentAddressFrom(first))
                    select i;"

Comment: i was thinking `where i.IsDifferentAddressFrom(first) select i;`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
List<GroupSummary> result = dictionary[key].Skip(1)
                                           .Where(x=>(x.PayToStr1+
                                                      x.PayToStr2+
                                                      x.PayToCity+
                                                      x.PayToState)!=
                                                      (dictionary[key][0].PayToStr1+
                                                       dictionary[key][0].PayToStr2+
                                                       dictionary[key][0].PayToCity+
                                                       dictionary[key][0].PayToState))
                                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your Question:**

> Finding the items in a list that differ from the first item in the list.

Here's a solution for a simple list of integers:

```cs
var items = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 4, 6, 1, 9};

var query = items
    .Skip(1)
    .Distinct()
    .Where(x => x != items.First())
    .OrderBy(x => x);

foreach (int item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2
3
4
6
7
9
```

---

It is easy to extend this query to work with your `GroupsSummary` class. Just define an instance method (or an extension method if you do not own the `GroupsSummary` class) to check for the "equivalence" of two `GroupsSummary` objects:

```
public bool IsEquivalentTo(GroupsSummary other)
{
    return
        this.PayToStr1.Equals(other.PayToStr1) &&
        this.PayToStr2.Equals(other.PayToStr2) &&
        this.PayToCity.Equals(other.PayToCity) &&
        this.PayToState.Equals(other.PayToState);
}
```

The `Where` constraint in the LINQ query above then simply becomes:

```
.Where(x => !x.IsEquivalentTo(items.First())
```